# (SDCAlertView) Functions in AlertAction handler are not called

Tags: ios, uialertcontroller, dismiss, sdcalertview, sdcalertcontroller

I would like to process the value in the textfield of alert controller after users tap an AlertAction (such as a "send button" maybe) on the alert controller without making it dismiss.

I knew that the built-in UIAlertController from Apple would naturally dismiss after users tap any button on the alert controller.  So I chose [SDCAlertView](https://cocoapods.org/pods/SDCAlertView) (from [CocoaPods](https://cocoapods.org/pods/SDCAlertView)), which does not dismiss after users' tapping button.  However, I got some problem.

I made an alert controller using SDCAlertView by the following code:

```
let alert = AlertController(title: "Title", message: "This is a message")
alert.addAction(AlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: .Default)) // the button do dismiss
alert.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler()

// the button that DO NOT dismiss
let sendAction = AlertAction(title: "Send", style: .Default, handler: { (sendAction) in

    // The following functions in the closure are not called after sendAction is tapped
    print("(alert.textFields![0].text)")
    // and further process to alert.textFields![0].text
    print("Send")
})

alert.addAction(sendAction)
alert.shouldDismissHandler = { $0!.title == "Dismiss" }
alert.present()
```

I would like to process the value in the textfield after the sendAction button was taped. However, the functions are not called. Is it possible to fix this problem?

Thank you!

Comment: Does this work if you remove the `shouldDismissHandler`? If it does, it might indicate a bug in the library.